# java swing remember Login and password and another text field :)

Tags: java

So we want to make our swing application to remembet our last choices(login,pasw,smtng) when we start the program.

So the easiest way probably would be to save the entered values to the file and then read from it, and auto connect somewhere :)

But I have a feeling that Java has a smarter way to remember values (I’m making smtng like putty.exe) JDBC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to save user settings in java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784657/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-user-settings-in-java-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Preference API`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) will help