# Java credential storage framework

Tags: java, storage, credentials

Is there a freely available credential storage framework for Java?

I have a desktop application that needs to store the users' credentials to external systems.

I'm just wondering if someone already has a framework to make this easy.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227005/mac-os-x-keychain-access-in-java-for-generic-passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use encrypted preferences, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784657/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-user-settings-in-java-application). Yes really, just click on this link and you will be amazed. (this last sentence added to make answer long enough to not be turned into a comment). :-p

Comment: :) It would be nice to have one or more solutions regarding how to deal with the key to the encrypted store as a proper framework would do, though... anyway I think the answer to my question is "not for desktop apps" and I can start with encrypted prefs and build my own.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Credential Store Framework (CSF)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/core.1111/e10043/devcsf.htm) with Java API provided by Oracle.

Comment: That appears to be only available in Oracle's application server. I need something for my desktop application.