# How can I store a program password in the OS keystore?

Tags: java, keystore

I am currently developing a Java application on a Mac. I know that there is the keystore from Apple and I want to securely store a password within that keystore.

According to Apple developers I can get the keystore with `keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("KeychainStore", "Apple");`

Now my question is: How can I store the password and how can I get the password back again?
I have read a lot about keystores but I do not know, how an implementation would look like.

And how can I get the built-in keystore from Windows / Linux?

Comment: Probably you would need to implement it yourself with C code and native methods.

Comment: Keystores are meant for [public key infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). They are not what you're looking for.

Comment: Then what am I looking for? I know several different programs that auro insert the password. How can i achieve that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MacOS. Is [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085) what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/04-JavaUIToolkits/JavaUIToolkits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001901-210260) was the information on how to get that keystore. I looked in mine (currently working on a MacBook) and I have several program passwords stored into there...

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227005/mac-os-x-keychain-access-in-java-for-generic-passwords).

Comment: Okay that helps foe mac. How can I achieve this on Windows?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard password manager in Windows.

Comment: There is Credential Manager in Windows 10 https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.security.KeyStore` was **not** created to deal with passwords. It is a storage facility for cryptographic keys and certificates. While you can try to use it to store passwords since it can for example store private keys, I would advise you against that, because KeyStore's API is cumbersome and was not designed for your use case.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

#### How to store passwords in Windows, Linux or macOS

What you need instead is [Keychain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)) in macOS and similar tools in other operating systems. Since you are also asking about Windows and Linux, you might be interested in the [Java Keyring](https://github.com/javakeyring/java-keyring) library. It stores passwords in:

1. [Keychain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)) on macOS
2. [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager) on Windows
3. [DBus Secret Service](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/latest/) on GNOME

Here's how to use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Keyring keyring = Keyring.create();
    String serviceName = "test-app";
    String accountName = "test-account";
    keyring.setPassword(serviceName, accountName, "test-password");
    String password = keyring.getPassword(serviceName, accountName);
    System.out.println(password);
}
```

Gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.javakeyring:java-keyring:1.0.1'
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.javakeyring</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-keyring</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to support desktop environments other than GNOME you would probably have to come up with your own solution or search for a different library, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Keystores are there for a reason other than what you're looking for, public key infrastructure(I think this was mentioned). You can't store a password in a keystore. You said you're doing this on Windows, right? I don't think Windows allows something like what you're looking for. Use a different device, or try using a different type of code.