# How can I make my .jar resource files point to the right directory

Tags: java, javafx

So I have cleaned and build it my project as a runnable jar file. There are some scenes that need to get data from files in the project. But for some reason, the file path's are not correct. My project in ide is like this

[image]

The path in my project is "src\ch\makery\address\util\settings.xml" but when I run my .jar file it becomes c:\users\bob\Desktop\src\ch\makery\address\util\settings.xml which will than throw a FileNotFoundException, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Don't use the file api to access resources. Use the classloader/class to access the resource url/a stream created from the resource entry of the jar. You may also need to tell your ide to include the resource files in the jar. Note that writing is not possible in this case. If you need to write to the file, create a copy of the settings in a convenient place unless the file already exists. You could e.g. [store the settings in the home directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3784695/2991525)

Comment: So I can't just save everything in my jar file, I would need to save it on the user's computer? And use that path to read/write when needed.

Comment: @fabian do you have any good example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your resource files using `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream()` then you wont get `FileNotFoundException` after exporting project to runable `jar`

```
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("ch\\makery\\address\\util\\settings.xml"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Comment: Don't use backslashes for the path. Use normal slashes. Furthermore it's probably better to use the classloader used to load the class iding the resource instead of the system classloader. E.g. `DateUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/ch/makery/address/util/settings.xml")`. Moreover there are better classes for reading xml files than `BufferedReader`...

Comment: @fabian I am reading the xml using jaxb. I just need to get the file path.

Comment: @C.Ikongo Using forward slash also gives null pointer exception ?

Comment: @UmerFarooq yeah, I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I have spent some much hours trying to fix this bug. Is there a working java project or code someone can post?

Comment: @C.Ikongo Make sure you used `ch/makery/address/util/settings.xml` not `src/ch/makery/address/util/settings.xml`

Comment: @UmerFarooq it worked, I just had some typos and missed placed some files. How do I get the path? Or would I have to read and write them into a temp file and use that?

Comment: @C.Ikongo `ch/makery/address/util/settings.xml` is actually path to `settings.xml` file.. what do you mean by getting path here??